# How to choose between Mac Laptop and Desktop

Tags: mac, laptop, desktop-computer

I am looking at getting a Mac soon for both iPhone development, and video editing. Should I be looking at a desktop or MacBook? I do not plan for the machine to move from my desk at home, so portability is not an issue, however it will be next to both a windows 7 desktop as well as a Linux laptop with dock.

Main things that I'm concerned about is whether or not a MacBook has the power needed to do the video editing that I'm planning on doing and whether or not I can afford a desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not planning on moving it then a tower (`Mac Pro`) would be my recommendation. You can run it faster, it's more expandable, and in general has more options. You can hook multiple monitors up to it, add in another keyboard / mouse, expand the RAM to [an obscene amount](http://chris.pirillo.com/mac-pro-memory-8gb-16gb-or-32gb-ram/). Also the probability of something breaking or needing to be repaired is much lower then a laptop.

Comment: This is a sensible suggestion. Having an expandable mac might mean he wouldn't need the windows 7 desktop or the linux laptop, since both OSes can run natively on the mac.

Comment: It's also very expensive, depending on how much video editing you need to do, an iMac would be fine if you're on a budget.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not moving it then I wold plump for a desktop.

That being said I do love my macbook, sometimes you want to type on the bed.  But I would say if you need to be videoediting etc then you want to be getting a MacBook Pro rather than just a macbook.

If money is no object then a Mac Pro is nice but a beefy iMac would probably do everything you want and save you a chunk of money.

Comment: The iMac comes with other limitations like you can't stick three additional monitors on that.

Answer (score 1):

A specced up imac will only cost you as much as a macbook pro, and less than a mac pro and the new ones are very capable machines. I recently bought a 27" imac with a i7 quad core and 8GB of ram and it flies.